# SimpleDateFormat can parse date on android 4.0+ but fails on android 2.3 -

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

This is due to different jdk versions on android.

```
  String string = "Tue Oct 16 00:00:55 IST 2012";
  Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(string);
```

and also tried

```
String string = "Tue Oct 16 00:00:55 IST 2012";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC' yyyy").parse(string);
```

adding Locale in SimpleDateFormat constructor has no effect.

I have searched and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016582/android-simpledateformat-fails-to-parse-datetime-works-fine-on-sun-1-6-jre)  but can't find any workaround.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What do you mean by fails ? Some output / stack trace would be nice.

Comment: Can you specify the error you are getting?

Comment: I was getting unparsable date exception.

Comment: My problem fixed solution from this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299837/simpledateformat-unparseable-date-exception